# WP7 Bing Maps navigate to a ZIP code

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

This is really simple, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet. On Bing Maps for Windows Phone 7, how do I navigate to a ZIP code? I just want to center and zoom the map to a specific ZIP code. Is this possible without knowing the long/lat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of the tools this isn't possible.

You'll have to [get the lat/long for the ZIP code](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=convert+zip+code+to+lat+long) and then manipulate the map accordingly.

Hopefully, [CivicAddressResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.civicaddressresolver%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) will be implemented in an update soon so that this can be done with the SDK on the device.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the GeoCodeService from WP7?  I've been attempting to do that which would allow this kind of Zip to Location function.  The problem I've found is that the `Credentials` type in the Phone map SDK seems incompatible with the GeoCodeService `Credentials`.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones No, sorry, I've not tried it. I suggest asking a new question about this.